# CRS not working as it should when exporting

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

My QGIS is displaying as being in British National Grid, however whenever I export data and open it up elsewhere the projection displays as longitude/latitude. Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?
This is the export box
[image]

This is the resulting projection when added back into QGIS
[image]

I can convert it to an ESRI shapefile and open it up in the correct projection, I just wondered if there was a way to fix it so I could convert straight to a tab file?

Comment: Hard to tell without some details about how you are exporting it (geoJSON? That shouldn't be used for non-lat-long coords - shapefile?) or where you are opening it up - other people's QGIS? Can we get a copy of a sample export you have made? Are you talking about the data projection or the project projection that QGIS uses for displaying its map canvas?

Comment: QGIS display and layer information is different. I think your QGIS map canvas is displaying your data in British National Grid; it translates for displaying purposes. right click on your layer and select "properties" and you'll see the native srs of your data. if you want the data to be in other srs, then use ```reproject layer``` tool, and export the output.

Comment: when you go under the properties of your loaded layer in the said project in British National Grid CRS, what CRS doe it shows?, does it show British National Grid? normally the layer takes that CRS showed under layer properties when you export it or are you adding it to a new project or a project with layers in the geographic coordinate system

Comment: I have exported a polygon from a BNG shapefile by right clicking on the layer, export, save as tab file. When I open it up again in qgis it is stated as an unnamed-projected layer in the layer properties setting. If I open it in mapinfo (where I want it) the projection comes up as long/lat and doesn't change when manually selecting the correct projection. I can make it work extracting it as a shapefile and then opening it up in mapinfo but I just wondered of there was a way to change it so I could just extract straight to a tab

Comment: before you export the layer, what is the CRS shown under layer properties and then source, when you double click on it?, because it inherits that CRS by defualt.

Comment: or alternatively, open the prj file and see the parameters in that file using notepad.

Comment: They are both displayed as british national grid. Even in the export window it states british national grid

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the clarification

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you convert the data into some other format than MapInfo? Try for example GeoPackage or GML. It may be that the not-so-much-used MapInfo driver would need an update. You can also convert into MID/MIF and do the same with MapInfo. Report the differences in coordinate systems which are stored into MID/MIF if there are any.

Comment: It seems exporting as a shapefile and then opening that up as a MapInfo tab file loads the layer in the correct projection. Exporting as a MIF results in the same misprojection issue.